# The resource cannot be found error in web API MVC 4 Masterpage Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Web api looks working and it dispalys data in json format

```
http://localhost:55304/api/InsuranceCompanyRegistration
```

my routeConfig looks like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And my webApiConfig :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

[image: Error]

[image: API]

My controller Calss:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DoctorsAndMedicines_Client.Controllers
{
    public class InsuranceCompanyRegistrationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /InsuranceCompanyRegistration/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @Ciwan please see my screenshot

Comment: On top of your Controller class, do you have a route attribute set? Show us your controller code too.

Comment: @Ciwan Controller class updated

Comment: @Ciwan please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename Your controller from **InsuranceCompanyRegisterationController** to **HomeController**

Comment: What is the URL That Causes this Error?

Comment: The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @IvinRaj  I edited the answer check it out , and tell me what you get ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147963/discussion-between-alameerashraf-and-ivin-raj).